# What is the relationship (similarity or otherwise) between negation and dual of a proposition?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, propositional-calculus

According to Rosen (in Discrete Mathematics and its Applications), we can get the dual of a compound proposition by substituting $\vee, \wedge, T \text{ and }F$ with $\wedge, \vee, F \text{ and }T$ respectively. Which essentially means

$$(p \vee q)^* = (p \wedge q)$$

But if $T^* = F$, then why not $p^* = \neg p$ ? A proposition $p$ holds some truth value. So if the dual of $T$ is $F$, then why not the dual of $p$ is $\neg p$?

Also, in addition to conjunction to disjunction (and vice versa) and $T$ to $F$ (and vice versa) what other identities do duals have?

Comment: The questions in your title and the body do not match. To answer the title: Your very example shows that duality and negation are not the same.

Comment: @user3482749 Edited the title.